# Ms Crm 2011 Forms: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I got an error in PageLoader.js, I did not change anything. Here is the error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

It prevent to load my custom javascript files on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used openEntityForm in my custom javascript file. I did not send lookup's parameterType in function. It did not cause an error. but I had an lookup(customerid) in account type. That caused an error. So I sent parameterType = Account and that fixed the problem